# Python3.8 asyncio behavior difference between Windows and Unix

Tags: unix, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I am working on script where I will be dealing with huge amount of data to process via python.

I have written a script using asyncio in python3.8 on windows box which is working perfectly fine but when I execute the same script on unix on python3.8 its completing the execution but not terminating the program at the end. Seems like its not release resources/lock.

When I debug further, found that on windows the asyncio uses ProactorEventLoop whereas on Unix it uses _UnixSelectorEventLoop, But not sure if this affect by any means.

I cant share the full script but it follows below structure:

```
import asyncio

async def myCoroutine():
    print("My Coroutine")

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(myCoroutine())
    print("Execution Completed")
finally:
    print("Closing the loop")
    loop.close()
    print("loop Closed")

Output:
Execution Completed
Closing the loop
loop closed
```

But program is not terminating.

Is anyone faced the similar issue before? Any inputs?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I've tried your code on Ubuntu 20.10, and the output is the following: https://imgur.com/a/tEIFIbb

Comment: On windows 10 the output is the same...  https://imgur.com/a/6P2RXQT

Comment: 3.8.5 on both windows and ubuntu.